# Function to get init.el file loading times multiple times

Tags: init-file

Yesterday I declared emacs bankruptcy and now I'm writing my init.el file from scratch.

I'd like to call a function several times within my init.el file to output the current loading times.
I've found this piece of code which only tells the final loading time:

```el
(when window-system
  (let ((elapsed (float-time (time-subtract (current-time)
                                            emacs-start-time))))
    (message "Loading %s...done (%.3fs)" load-file-name elapsed))

  (add-hook 'after-init-hook
            `(lambda ()
               (let ((elapsed (float-time (time-subtract (current-time)
                                                         emacs-start-time))))
                 (message "Loading %s...done (%.3fs) [after-init]"
                          ,load-file-name elapsed)))
            t))
```

So far I failed any attempt to 'extract' some bits and bobs from there to create the function I look for.

Although I've using Emacs for several years, I have no idea about elisp. All I do is copy + paste + edit code, which is a shame.

Please don't accuse me of not even try it because I had spent a good couple of hours with zero results. I'd put some of the code I've written but I don't think it would help to anything apart from embarrass myself.

I know that there are several packages which help profiling Emacs configuration files but that's not really what I'm kindly asking here. I'd like some help to write a little function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, I think I managed to do it. This is what I've written:

```el
(defun get-time (package-loaded)
  (let ((elapsed (float-time (time-subtract (current-time) emacs-start-time))))
    (message "loading %s package...done (%.3fs)" package-loaded elapsed)))
```

Then I can call that function like this:

```el
(get-time "use-package")
...
(get-time "yasnippet")
...
```